# Python Amazon MWS Api 400 Client Error Bad request

Tags: python, amazon-mws

Hi I am using this github code to link to amazon mws api to fetch current listed order.
[Github python-amazon-aws](https://github.com/czpython/python-amazon-mws).

My Code is:

```
import mws

auth = mws.Orders(access_key='AKIAJHSXMwdwdL4XJT7NVLAQ', secret_key='xbY5YTa4wwcqMD9dMJDOA0T3iRSL67vSYdRFz+Y4wGR', account_id='A3AZIT4DFSLU02M7', region='IN', domain='', uri="", version="", auth_token="")

auth.list_orders(marketplaceids='A21TJRUUN4KGV', created_after='2015-06-01', created_before=None, lastupdatedafter=None, lastupdatedbefore=None, orderstatus=(), fulfillment_channels=(), payment_methods=(), buyer_email=None, seller_orderid=None, max_results='100')
```

Access Key, Secret Key and Account Id changed for security. the first two line of code works fine. On adding the 3rd line I am getting this error:

```
$python Orders.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Orders.py", line 5, in <module>
    auth.list_orders(marketplaceids='A21TJRUUN4KGV', created_after='2015-06-01', created_before=None, lastupdatedafter=None, lastupdatedbefore=None, orderstatus=(), fulfillment_channels=(), payment_methods=(), buyer_email=None, seller_orderid=None, max_results='100')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_amazon_mws-0.6-py2.7.egg/mws/mws.py", line 421, in list_orders
return self.make_request(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_amazon_mws-0.6-py2.7.egg/mws/mws.py", line 210, in make_request
raise error
mws.mws.MWSError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
I was passing the the marketplace_id as a string.
The correct way is to pass marketplace_id as a list like

```
marketplaceids = ['A21TJRUUN4KGV',]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not into python but only thing i can think of is there is a space at the end of your secret_key, I am not sure if AWS python requires ISO date format.

Try using this scratch pad and check if you get same results.

And if the details you've shown in your question are your real AWS credentials then please change them to XXXXXXXXXX

Comment: No I changed my credentials. And I used scratchpad and it worked fine.